# Validation rule to restrict editing a record

Tags: validation-rule, configuration

I have two fields on object - Apple__c. 
Field 1: apple1
Field 2: apple2

I have written a validation rule.

`NOT(ISNEW()) && AND( NOT( ISBLANK( Apple1__c ) ), ISBLANK( Apple2__c ) )`

This rule will not allow user to Edit the record once it is created.

Here, i need one exception. The rule should allow the user edit when Apple1__c is not populated.

Please guide me, which function do i use here?

Comment: try `NOT( OR(ISNEW(), ISBLANK( Apple1__c ) ))`

Comment: this not the expected behavior. my existing functionality should retain and it should allow the user to edit the record when there is no value in Apple1__c field. Currently user is not allowed to edit the record. I need this exception to be excluded. please let know any suggetions.

Comment: it does what you were asking: 
 1)not allow user to Edit the record once it is created
 2)allow the user edit when Apple1__c is not populated
What is not expected here?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, i agree. When i updated my rule as above, system is displaying error when i am editing and updating Apple1__c filed, this has to be exempted.

Comment: 1.User will be able to create a record with out populating Apple1__c and Apple2__c.  2. User should be allowed to edit and update only Apple1__c. Apple2__c will be populated, so am involving that here.

Comment: If I understood your requirement correctly then it is as follows: 1. User will be able to create a record with out populating Apple1__c and Apple2__c 2, User will be able to edit or update Apple1__c if that is blank. 3. If Apple1__c is not blank then user cannot change the value again. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly then it is as follows:

1. User will be able to create a record with out populating Apple1__c and Apple2__c
2. User will be able to edit or update Apple1__c if that is blank.
3. If Apple1__c is not blank then user cannot change the value again. Is that correct? If it is yes, then use this code for Apple1__c:

   **AND(NOT(ISNEW()), NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(Apple1__c))))**

In the edit mode, if Apple1__c is not blank and user can change the value again then, do not need to use validation rule.

You can take care the Apple2__c field separately using this kind of logic.

Comment: Great!! this is working fine. But here, once if i update apple1__c and if i want to update it again this rule is not allowing. Is there a way that we can bypass this?? thanks a ton for your response..

Comment: If you want to update Apple1__c again, then whats the need of validation rule?